# Cross-compiling Linux kernel fails on bzImage

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, cross-compilation

I want to compile a Linux kernel from scratch for the arm64 (aarch64) platform, used for booting a Raspberry Pi 4.

The host is amd64 and is running a Debian-variant (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS)

I created the following script, that tries to do everything:

```
###### Build Environment ######

# download and install required packages for host system that will do the compiling
apt install build-essential libgmp-dev libmpfr-dev libmpc-dev libisl-dev libncurses5-dev bc git-core bison flex

# create temporary Build Environment in RAM
PREFIX=/tmp/BE
mkdir -p ${PREFIX}
umount ${PREFIX} 2>&1 > /dev/null
mount -t tmpfs tmpfs ${PREFIX}

# binutils:
# download binutils from ftp.gnu.org and compile and install it to the host [redacted]
cd obj-binutils
../binutils-${BINUTILSVERSION}/configure --prefix=${PREFIX}/binutils --target=aarch64-linux-gnu --disable-nls
make install

# gcc:
# download gcc from ftp.gnu.org and compile and install it to the host [redacted]
# configure gcc:
../gcc-${GCCVERSION}/configure --prefix=${PREFIX}/gcc --target=aarch64-linux-gnu \
--with-newlib --without-headers --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-threads \
--disable-libssp --disable-decimal-float --disable-libquadmath --disable-libvtv \
--disable-libgomp --disable-libatomic --enable-languages=c
# install gcc:
make all-gcc -j${THREADS}
make install-gcc
# test with:
${PREFIX}/gcc/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -v
# libgcc optional [skipped]


###### Linux ######

# note that we download from raspberrypi linux git
LINUXBRANCH="rpi-5.10.y"
mkdir -p ${PREFIX}/linux
cd ${PREFIX}/linux
git clone --depth=1 -b ${LINUXBRANCH} https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git
mkdir kernel-out

# copy the compiled gcc/binutils binaries to linux /bin directory
cd linux
mkdir bin
mv ${PREFIX}/binutils/bin/* ${PREFIX}/linux/linux/bin/
mv ${PREFIX}/gcc/bin/* ${PREFIX}/linux/linux/bin/

# RPi4 specific configuration
KERNEL=kernel8
make O=../kernel-out/ ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=${PREFIX}/linux/linux/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu- bcm2711_defconfig

# Linux menuconfig
make O=../kernel-out/ ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=${PREFIX}/linux/linux/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu- menuconfig

# Linux build
make -j${THREADS} O=../kernel-out/ ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
# note, produced result:
ls -l /tmp/BE/linux/kernel-out/vmlinux
#in my case:
#-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 26179040 feb 25 22:48 /tmp/BE/linux/kernel-out/vmlinux


# Linux compress vmlinux into bzImage
# note: pwd = /tmp/BE/linux/linux
make bzImage O=../kernel-out/ ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
find ${PREFIX} -iname vmlinuz
```

But I am currently stuck at the last step, creating the bzImage from the vmlinux. Apparently, you cannot just compress vmlinux into vmlinuz, it needs to be created with `make bzImage`. But this produces the error:

```
# reminder: pwd = /tmp/BE/linux/linux
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/BE/linux/kernel-out'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'bzImage'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/BE/linux/kernel-out'
make: *** [Makefile:185: __sub-make] Error 2
```

Any help on the bzImage problem is welcome, but generally my question refers to the overall process of cross compiling a linux kernel for ARM64 platform.

Any advice is welcome on whether I am doing the right thing with GCC and binutils here. I do get some GCC errors here and there. But vmlinux did compile. I would like to test the produced vmlinux first by converting it to a vmlinuz and modifying an existing SD card image from say Ubuntu.

I hope to edit my question so that the script would be useful for other people wanting to compile ARM64 Linux kernel for their RPi4 or other device.

Comment: bzImage is the image for an i386 boot floppy, so it does not make any sense to try and build it on ARM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the correct procedure to compile a Linux kernel is different for each platform:

```
# on 32-bit x86
make bzImage

# on 64-bit x86
make zImage

# on 64-bit ARM
make Image

# search for compiled linux kernel in current directory
find ./ -iname "*Image"
```